# Hover psuedo class not applied when selecting, even when selecting disabled

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I am developing a website and I need the functionality of being able to press down in one place, hold, and continually move downwards while elements' hover is getting activated. I have a codepen demonstrating the issue [here](https://codepen.io/UltimateProGrammer/pen/KKVLBBd).

As you can see in the pen, the second div's hover will not get activated if you start dragging from the first div. Is there a way to fix this? I am open to javascript solutions, though pure css would be nice.

```css
.unselectable {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size:2em;
}

.hover:hover {
  color:white;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: gray; color:white;" class="unselectable">Start pressing down here.</div>
<div class="unselectable hover" id="text">Drag to here.</div>
<div style="font-size:0.5em;">Try hovering over the 'Drag to here.' div without selecting anything first. That is what it should look like when you do it while selecting things.</div>
```

I am using Safari 13.1.1. As pointed out in the comments, it seems to work on chrome.

Update: I have tested it with chrome and firefox. It works on both, so the issue seems to be with safari. It seems safari has some weird behavior with `-webkit-user-select-none` so that is most likely the issue.

Comment: It's working fine for me. I'm using Google Chrome by the way. You should mention the browser and browser version you are using where this isn't working

Comment: Sorry, I should have. I will edit the question.

Comment: The  `:hover` pseudo-class always happens when you hover. Use JavaScript `touchstart` and `mousedown`.

Comment: I would try to hack it with `.unselectable:active + :hover { background-color: [colorwithouthover] }`.

Comment: @Deykun Sadly, that does not work. It seems like `:active` isn't activated if you start from the first div.

Comment: You can try with :focus or adding tabindex="1" to that div or switching a tag div with button.